# Resizing superview that's an embedded UIViewController to fit subviews

Tags: objective-c, swift, resize, autolayout, interface-builder

**Here's the scenario:**

I have a segmented control that toggles between hiding/displaying two views that each embed a view controller (via use of the interface builder's provided "Container View").  For simplicity's sake, in each embedded view controller I have a single subview with fixed leading and trailing spacing to its superview's margins along with fixed top and bottom vertical spacing between the subview and its superview's top and bottom layout guides.  If the superview (i.e. the embedded View Controller) is a fixed width and height, these constraints should fulfill the x-position, width, y-position, and height requirements (respectively).

**Here's the problem:**

I want to add a height constraint to the subview.  If instead of embedding a view controller in the container view I had just placed the subview (with the added height constraint) inside a container view (that didn't have a fixed height constraint), the container view would be automatically resized to fit its subview.  However, because the container view embeds a view controller, auto-layout doesn't consider the constraints set between View Controllers.

In other words, I want the "Container View" (or the embedded View Controller) to be resized in height according to the subview's height constraint.

**Here's the type of solution that I'm looking for:**

Ideally, I would like the solution to this problem to be as clean as possible, which in my eyes means:

1) Sticking with the interface builder and storyboarding.

2) IBOutlets for NSLayoutConstraints.

3) Subclassing if need be.

However, any working solution besides the one that I proposed (which was to not embed a View Controller) would help me out.